# Run Keyword If - return OK result when no execution was done

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I also have a problem with the keyword "**Run Keyword If**".
I've investigated almost all articles from stackoverflow and tried a lot of times different solutions, unfortunately no improvements.
I post that article with a hope that someone will show me the correct hint.

The problem is in following:

I try to make a checker to check if a field exist, the field is following

```
<input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-aaf80655-9ef4-37cc-6026-2f5989e82df1" value="Please select organisation">
```

If the field exist, then should execute keyword "Select-ORG" if not, then skip.

So the code that I tried to manipulate is displayed below (UPD:11.07):

```
<li class="step active" data-order="1">
    <div class="step-title waves-effect"><b>General info</b></div>
    <div class="step-content" style="left: 0%; display: block;">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <div class="btn-types">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" data-activity-type="1" class="btn btn-primary btn-activity-type selected"><span>Event</span></button>
                        <button type="button" data-activity-type="2" class="btn btn-primary btn-activity-type "><span>Repeating</span></button>
                        <input type="hidden" id="activity_type" name="activity_type" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <br>

            <div class="input-field col s12 ">
                <div class="select-wrapper"><span class="caret">▼</span>
                    <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-e1b60306-a7d2-ef9c-ecc9-3df0dec2ac24" value="Please select organisation">
                    <ul id="select-options-e1b60306-a7d2-ef9c-ecc9-3df0dec2ac24" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 1181px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: none;">
                        <li class=""><span>Please select organisation</span></li>
                        <li class=""><span>ORG-WITH-IMAGE</span></li>
                        <li class=""><span>ORG-WITHOUT-IMAGE</span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <select id="organisation_id" name="organisation_id" class="initialized">
                        <option value="0">Please select organisation</option>
                        <option value="782">ORG-WITH-IMAGE</option>
                        <option value="783">ORG-WITHOUT-IMAGE</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <label for="organisation_id">Organisation</label>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
</li>
```

The Robot Framework code is following:

```
*** Settings ***
    Resource              Settings.robot
    Resource              Variables.robot
    Library               OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***

Check create Event
  Open SiteURL
  Login as Provider
  Events - Add new

*** Keywords ***

Events - Add new
    Sleep   1
    Go To     ${UrlSite}/cms/activity?t=1
    Sleep   1
    Click Element     xpath=(//a[@class="add-btn-new"])[1]
    Sleep   1
    Log To Console    Checke-one
    Sleep   1
    Log To Console    Check-two
    ${CycleValue} =   Run Keyword And Return Status   Element Should Be Visible     //input[@class="select-dropdown"][1]
    Log To Console    Check-three
    Sleep   1
    Log To Console    Check-four
    Run keyword If  ${CycleValue} == "PASS"     Select-ORG
    Log To Console    Check-five
Select-ORG
    Sleep   1
    Click Element     xpath=(//input[@class="select-dropdown"])[1]
    Sleep   1
    Click Element     xpath=//div[@class="row"]/div/div/ul/li[last()]/span
    Sleep   1
```

[CMD display that all is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tesJd.jpg)

[The row that need to click is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Om4W.jpg)

Maybe is a problem with my environment:

- robotframework-3.0.2
- Python 2.7.11
- OS X El Capitan ver. 10.11.6

Comment: Looks like you might have a spelling error.. "Log To Console    Checke-one" the is an extra e in the end of Checke

Comment: It's a individual created keyword, special for case when required field exist, then "Run keyword If" will execute it.

Comment: @StefanE , it's not a problem, it's a message that I set. It's OK.

Comment: Does the `${CycleValue}` variable contain the value: `PASS`? Have you tried quoting: `"${CycleValue}" == "PASS" ` as both are strings.

Comment: @A.Kootstra, from the documentation, http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If , it results that I should indicate positive status, like "PASS". So that I did, but I didn't see that was done click on the required field.

Comment: Correct, in case it passes it *should* return `PASS` but I'm asking if it indeed *does* pass. Can you Log the content of the variable to the console to be sure?

Comment: @A.Kootstra, thanks, re-checked, the problem was that my xpath was met in several more places, when for my case it was disabled.

Comment: offtopic - do you really need all those `Sleep` ops? Looks like they are there to give time to the UI to react and display the needed element, but they are not a good practice - it may take as much as 50ms for something to appear, and you're wasting 950ms just because it's hardcoded; also, something may come up in 1100ms, but the case will fail (cause it didn't wait those extra 100ms). It is much better to use RF's `Wait Until Element Is Visible` (or enabled, depends on the case).

Comment: Thanks @Todor, you're right. I'll begin change `Sleep` with `Wait Until Element Is Visible` . But at that moment were needed to create ASAP all scripts on all functionalities, so I observed that some pages were slowly loading.

Comment: The `Wait Until` will make your scripts look better, they'll execute in less time ;)

Comment: You're right @Todor, I'll begin the big improvement as soon as I finish with that case  :)  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there - `Run Keyword And Return Status` does not return the strings 'PASS' / 'FAIL' though, it returns a true boolean `True` or `False`. So your check cannot ever succeed - it does string match comparison - but this simple change will do:

```
Run keyword If  ${CycleValue}     Select-ORG
```

If `${CycleValue}` is `True`, `Select-ORG` will be ran, otherwise - not.

Comment: thanks, you hint helped me to find solution.  The problem in xpath, duplications. So I investigated how to detect it for my case. Found solution and checked. It works. Xpath is following: `//li[@class="step active"]/div/div/div/div/input[@class="select-dropdown"][1]`

Comment: Well the hint is how the keyword actually works :) HTH. That xpath - don't use it - it's a hardcoded structure, literally saying "there should be a `li` with that class, then exactly 4 `div`s down take the `input` with the other class, which is the first one (if there are more than one `input`s with that class)". If the structure changes a little bit - there's a div going out or extra one coming in, or some of them changes to span - this will blow up.

Comment: Try with this one - `//li[@class="step active"]//input[@class="select-dropdown" and parent::div[@class="select-wrapper"]]`. It reads "somewhere below that `li` find an `input` with that class, and whose parent is a `div` with the other class"; this will protect you at least from structural changes.

Comment: Checked with your xpath, it works. Thanks a lot, now will know how to write more perfect xpath locators. You're right, design is unstable and could be changed, and then will begin the biggest correction :)